# JSLink button to open modal window

Tags: sharepoint-server, modal-dialog, jslink

I have created a JSLink file to open the edit form for a list item in a modal window. It works great on an Office 365 dev site, but when I try to use it within our on-premise SharePoint 2013 environment, I get a page not found error when clicking the "Send Comment to Manager" link. It's a standard task list, with no modifications.

I can manually open the link in the address bar without any issues, so the form is available.

[image: JSLink Display]

[image: Page not found error]

[JSLink Code](https://gist.github.com/jwstl/4eadfb6f1411380a2ec3a7e520fadeb6)

Comment: How about sharing your code? As a blind guess I would say the page you are requesting does not exist. Check your browser dev tools - there should be the reason for the 404.

Comment: The code is available via the https://gist.github.com/jwstl/4eadfb6f1411380a2ec3a7e520fadeb6 The issue was due to the URL path pointing to the page not being well formatted

Comment: So if you solved your problem you could either answer your own question or close it.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to change the URL to the form from this

```
/Lists/Staffing%20Scheduling%20Standard%20Work%20Tasks/CommentForm.aspx?ID=
```

to this

```
/sites/standardwork/Lists/Staffing%20Scheduling%20Standard%20Work%20Tasks/CommentForm.aspx?ID=
```